# Include check_command with nagios/icinga alerts

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

Is there a way to include the check_command that is being used when being alerted via Nagios or Icinga.

Example:

define command {
        command_name    check-x-dc6.x-icmp
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H IP -w 100.0,20% -c 500.0,60%
}

Basically what im looking for is the command_line of this command to be included in the alerting system for nagios/icinga?

Answer (score 0):

Include the `$HOSTCHECKCOMMAND$` macro in your notification command. (Or `$SERVICECHECKCOMMAND$` for service checks).

See the [list of macros](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/3/en/macrolist.html) that you can use for more information.